# AWS Lambda - ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to GET a single item from DynamoDB in Postman. but I keep receiving the error below from my lambda code:

"ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema."

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update( {
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const dynamodbTableName = 'customers';

const healthPath = '/health';
const customerPath = '/customer';
```

This is my lambda handler

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  let response;

  switch(true) {
    case event.httpMethod === 'GET' && event.path === healthPath:
      response = buildResponse(200);
      break;
    case event.httpMethod === 'GET' && event.path === customerPath:
      response = await getCustomer(event.queryStringParameters.customer_id);
      break;
    default:
      response = buildResponse(404, '404 Not Found');
  }
  return response;
}
```

This function GETs the info of a customer

```
async function getCustomer(customer_id) {
  const params = {
    TableName: dynamodbTableName,
    Key: {
      'customer_id': customer_id
    },
  }
  return await dynamodb.get(params).promise().then((response) => {
    return buildResponse(200, response.Item);
  }, (error) => {
    // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERORR <-------------------------------------------------------
    console.error('GET ERROR --->', error);
  });
}
```

This is my callback function

```
function buildResponse(statusCode, body) {
  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}
```

This is a picture of the schema. All attributes are strings except for customer_id and shared_id.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The erro is showing table `customers` do not have `customer_id` as key. Provide us the schema of `customers` table

Comment: @SubhashisPandey I just uploaded a picture of the schema. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot doesn't include any information about the schema. Click "View table details" to see it. What is probably happening is that your primary key consists of a HASH key (customer id) and a RANGE key (email?). Or from a HASH key only, but not customer id (email?)

In first case, to get a customer, you need to pass both the HASH and the RANGE key.

Based on the screenshot, you need:

```
async function getCustomer(customer_id, email) {
  const params = {
    TableName: dynamodbTableName,
    Key: {
      'customer_id': customer_id, 'email_address': email
    },
  }
  return await dynamodb.get(params).promise().then((response) => {
    return buildResponse(200, response.Item);
  }, (error) => {

  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I just uploaded a picture with the table details. I believe my primary key is only customer_id. I don't believe that it consists of a range key/hash key. The only other custom key I created was the sort key (which is the email address). hope this helps!

Comment: Sort key and range key is the same thing

Comment: that was it! Thanks a ton, I was stuck on this issue for weeks. May I ask if you knew the solution from experience, or did you do some digging (like looking into the aws docs?)

Comment: @Chris Rose: DocumentDb has some intricacies that take some time to learn. I strongly suggest you do some reading first and don't follow trial and error practice. Otherwise you will finally learn what is needed the hard way.

Comment: Hello again @kgiannakakis. I’m struggling with implementing one of the last functionalities of my site via AWS. I know this is a different problem than the one I posted above, but I’d really appreciate any help/advice you might have. 

The problem is that I’m able to POST an item successfully via Postman, however when I try to POST an item with axios I get a 404 response error, and I'm not sure why. Hope you’re able to help. More information can be found here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935863/cant-post-item-to-my-dynamodb-table-with-axios