# Can't POST item to my DynamoDB table with axios

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I’m trying to POST an item in VS Code to my DynamoDB table via axios. I’m able to POST an item successfully via Postman, however when I try to POST an item with axios I get a 404 response error (below).

[image]

I’m wondering if I’m missing something when trying to POST an item via axios (below).

```
axios({
    'method': 'post',
    'url': 'https://na9blqj5y5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'data': {
      'body': eraseThis,
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return console.log('axiosResp', response);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error('axios', err))
```

One thought that I had is that I should be importing the AWS SDK and invoke my lambda function with my credentials from that (below)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

This is a successful POST request in Postman.

[image]

Now I'm getting a CORS error I had a few weeks ago (even after enabling CORS on the API resource in the API Gateway interface).

[image]

Below is the updated code using the aws-sdk

[image]

Comment: Please show an example of your working Postman request

Comment: @Phil So I recently tried to POST via Postman and I got the same error. Then I changed the integration request of the POST to be a lambda proxy (because this was my original implementation) and now Postman works again (screenshot above). However, I’m getting the same CORS errors that I had a few weeks ago after changing the POST to a lambda proxy (screenshot above). This doesn’t make sense to me because I made sure to enable CORS on the API resource via the API Gateway interface.

Comment: hey, @Phil just wanted to follow up to see if you got a chance to look at my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I did, but the call to dynamodb randomly started working. I think I had a syntax error, or something..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31874729)

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are hard to follow because they don't match.

- first screenshot url is a different api gateway endpoint address than the postman screenshot
- first uses the /test stage and the 2nd uses a /prod/customer

So right off I'm wondering if you just have different code deployed to different stages?  Assuming you've ruled that out though and that's not the case I *think* what you mean to say is that your axios call made via browser fails whereas postman works.

That's actually expected behavior because postman isn't a browser and bypasses the CORS restrictions that browsers implement.  There are plenty of existing questions here that explain that so I'm not going into that further.

I believe the fix for this is to update your lambda handler (the actual lambda proxy that returns a response) to always return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as [documented by AWS here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-enable-cors-proxy).  To allow all origins you can use a wildcard `*`.  ex:

```
headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
    }
```

Make sure you understand the implications of using `*`, which is a discussion for a different post.